# How can I send a html page (including the css) as pdf via mail?

Tags: python, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a web-based application that lets users collect certain information.

On the last page an analysis of the collected data is displayed. This is done partially by numbers and by changing the background colors of the fields in which the numbers are displayed.

After having looked at the analysis on his phone, the user is supposed to enter his email adress as well as his name in a form. Hitting the "Send" Button, it is my aim to send the user a pdf (or any kind of document that includes the html and the css code (because of the colors))via email. To make this more clear, the user is supposed to reveive a copy of the last page of the application. It has to be considered that the user is working on his phone, but the document he receives should be formatted to be viewed on a Computer.

Currently I use a printDiv() function that results in the opening of the printing menu, though in a preview only the html (without the css) is displayed.

Therefore, my questions are:

- How can I include the css to the preview? The css is determined in a javascript function (I am not using a seperate stylesheet as this is the only css code I need).

  ```
  $('#field').val(fieldValue); 
  {if (fieldValue> 85){
  $(this).css('background-color', '#008000');
    }
  else if (fieldValue>= 50 ){
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FFA500');
  }
  else 
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
  )
  ;}
  ```
- How can I then send the document via email? Is my current approach expedient? I am unsure about this, because the users will use the application exclusively with their phones and many do not support the print statement. My printDiv() function looks like this:

  ```
   function printDiv(divName) {
   var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write(printContents);
    w.print();
    w.close();
    }
  ```

How do I continue after this? I think I have to save the pdf to the server, send it from there and after that delete the document. Is this correct? I am happy about any advice. If possible I plan to work with python for the following steps.

I hope that I have precisely described my problems and appreciate every effort to help me!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not work with most email clients. In order for the css to work, it needs to be pulled out of a script and left static.

There are a multitude of email clients that work in differing ways with CSS. As an example, if you wanted to style H1, in email you can style it three ways:

Inline style (most effective):
`<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Hello</h1>`

Internal style sheet (limited effectiveness):

```
<head>
  <style>
    h1 {color: #ff0000;}
  </style>
</head>
```

External style sheet (very limited effectiveness):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Some email clients will not work with an external style sheet. Some will substitute their own styles for an Internal style sheet and many will block an External style sheet completely.

If you can inline your values, you should be able to send an html email styled to your choosing.

Comment: Hi gwally, 
I am not ready to send an email yet, my problem is that the css is not even displayed in the printing menu preview...